# Submit sem recarregar página cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Como faço para dar submit nas páginas sem recarregar com o cakephp?

Comment: Já tentou ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) e [`jQuery.serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var meuForm = $("#meuForm");
    meuForm.submit(function() {
        $.ajax(meuForm.attr("action"), {
            "type": meuForm.attr("type"),
            "data": meuForm.serialize()
        }).done(function(resultado) {
            //Troque isto pela sua mensagem customizada
            alert(resultado);
        }).fail(function(error) {
            //Troque isto pela sua mensagem customizada de erro
            alert(error);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form id="meuForm" method="POST" action="/sua rota cakephp">
    <input name="campo1" value="">
    <input name="campo2" value="">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: O Cake não tem nenhuma ferramente que simplifique o uso não?